# Problems with the German letter sharp S

Tags: font-encodings, latexmk, texpad

I am using the extra package `lstcustom` (https://github.com/markroyer/latex-syllabus/blob/master/lstcustom.sty) and have the problem, that the German letter 'ß' is not rendered properly.

My MWE is

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usepackage{lstcustom}

\title{Test}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        Größe
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I am a Mac user!

If I compile this with Texpad, everything looks fine:

[image: screenshot1]

But if I compile it via the console using `latexmk -cd -gg -lualatex -silent Test.tex`, I get the following output:

[image: screenshot2]

I've found out, that the problem is the line

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

in the `lstcustom.sty` file... But I do not know how to fix it. If I delete the line, all my listings are looking very different.

And I can't figure out the difference between the compilation of Texpad (which works) contrary to the compilation of `latexmk`.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is Texpad using `lualatex`? Your `latexmk` line is.

Comment: never use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with luatex but `\usepackage{fontspec}` afterwards may fix it or use pdftex not luatex

Comment: also do not use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` with luatex

Comment: I do not know, if Texpad using luatex. I think they are working with installer Tex distribution. The appropriate folder in the settings is `/Library/TeX/texbin` and I think I installed MacTeX.

Comment: But: In Texpad everything works fine, even the compilation... But I want to be able to compile the files correct out of the terminal (I have a script for compiling bunch of tex files at once).

Comment: presumably it works if you remove `-lualatex` from your commandline

Comment: Ahhh, that one was easy... Thank you! I replaced `-lualatex` with `-pdf` and everything works fine... Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Documents using

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

are written for 8-bit fonts and pdflatex, so you should use pdflatex or adjust the document to use the default `TU` (Unicode) encoding with lualatex

presumably it works if you remove `-lualatex` from your `latexmk` commandline (and possibly also explicitly force pdflatex by adding `-pdf`)